# How to create a vertex buffer that provides this pattern?

Tags: rendering, vertex-buffer

I have a series of vertices that I want to layout with the following configuration, but I haven't been able to find out how to do this with the square and X pattern.  Most of the time I have generally seen a quad split  into two triangles usually using triangle lists.  I suspect this is using triangle strips but I am not exactly sure how to do it.  Could anyone help?

[image: mesh]

Comment: Isn't it just quads split into four triangles? What have you tried already?

Comment: "I suspect this is using triangle strips" Why? seems like normal quads split to me.

Comment: @Byte56 I thought about just doing four triangles per quad but was wondering if there was a more optimal way or compact way to represent the pattern.

Comment: @concept3d I considered tri-strips only because it would likely be compact than tri-lists.  Plus given I've seen this pattern in several AAA games, I thought they'd also would have considered tri-strips over lists since they're more compact and from my reading, better performance.

Comment: @crancran AAA games 3d artists actually model the 3D meshes as 3D triangles the engine or some other tools optimize it to become triangle strips. Just in your case don't go for "better performance" because in your context it doesn't mean much, go for simplicity. Unless you are actually making a AAA game (which isn't the case).

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way to do this would be to build each subsquare as a triangle fan, with the center of the X as the first vert. But then you have to use degenerate triangles between each square as you move across the rows.

Possibly more wasteful but much easier to manage, do it all as individual GL_TRIANGLES, and use your index array to manually build the fans. Indices are cheap compared to verts, and you can get a lot of reuse out of each point.